# iOS - Object deallocation during execution

Tags: ios, memory, garbage-collection

Apple's Developer Reference mentions that a an object is deallocated if there are no strong reference to it. Can this happen if an instance method called from a weak reference is in the middle of execution?

For example, consider the below snippet -

```
@interface ExampleObject

- doSomething;

@end


@interface StrongCaller
@property ExampleObject *strong;
@end

@implementation StrongCaller


- initWithExampleInstance:(ExampleObject *) example
{
    _strong = example;
}

- doSomething
{
    ....
    [strong doSomething];
    ....
    strong = nil;
    ....
}

@end

@interface WeakCaller
@property (weak) ExampleObject *weak;
@end 

@implementation WeakCaller

- initWithExampleInstance:(ExampleObject *) example
{
    _weak = example;
}    

- doSomething
{
    ....
    [weak doSomething];
    ....
}

@end
```

Now, In main thread,

```
ExampleObject *object = [[ExampleObject alloc] init];
```

In Thread 1,

```
[[StrongCaller initWithExampleInstance:object] doSomething];
```

In Thread2,

```
[[WeakCaller initWithExampleInstance:object] doSomething];
```

Assuming that the main thread no longer holds a reference to object, what would happen if strong is set to nil, when [weak doSomething] is executing? Is the object GC'ed in this case?

Comment: Yep, it can happen in the middle of a method call on the object.  And the potential symptoms are quite unpredictable.

Comment: Okay. How can this be avoided? Also, does this not make a weak reference unsuitable for concurrent programming?

Comment: It can be avoided by keeping a strong reference somewhere.

Comment: @Pranav - Just a nitpick: Reference counting can be used to implement garbage collection.

Comment: @HotLicks ignore me. I really shouldn't be commenting after midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this problem happens during asynchronously blocks execution where there is impossible to avoid this problem by changing logic.

But if you are sure that you do not want to change logic you can use the same solution in your case. You should modify your method this way

```
- (void) doSomething
{
    Your_Class *pointer = self; //Now this local variable keeps strong reference to self
    if(pointer != nil){  // self is not deallocated
        ... your code here
    }
    //Here pointer will be deleted and strong reference will be released automatically 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Should this be done for all methods of the soft-referenced object for thread safety, including property accessors? Also, this behaviour seems a bit weird. One would assume ARC to automatically create a strong reference within methods, as the strategy mentioned above. This imposes a number of restrictions on the design.

Comment: Automatic creation of retain/release pair will cause significant drop in performance. So ARC does not do this. Yes, this operation should be done in every method. Automaticaly generated properties could be declared as atomic.

Comment: As I wrote this mechanism is also used for blocks. You can read about it here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018456/ios-blocks-and-strong-weak-references-to-self for example

Comment: Doesn't this simply move the problem around? What happens if the object is concurrently deallocated just before the strong reference is created on the first line?

Comment: Update: Tried it out and it still may go boom :-)

Comment: @Etan I have updated the answer. `if(pointer != nil){` line was added.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is sufficient. To be honest, I tried with Swift, but it should be the same behavior in Objc.

Putting a local variable there produces an implicit "retain" message that is sent to "self". If this message is sent while the object is being deallocated from a different thread, it will be a problem.

Could also be a Swift bug in my case as there's no way this can be implemented correctly if there is no internal locking going on that prevents object deallocation during an objc_msg_send call...
I even observed that "self" becomes released during the "... your code here" section..

Comment: @Etan `retain/release` are thread safe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713533/is-nsobjects-retain-method-atomic . So you should not worry about "If this message (an implicit "retain") is sent while the object is being deallocated from a different thread"